# How to hardware accelerate a box-shadow animation in CSS?

Tags: ios, css, webkit, hardware-acceleration

I am animating on a box-shadow with CSS. Using [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) program, I discovered that this animation alone is taking **35% of the CPU** on iOS Safari! The iPhone become hotter and hotter when I leave the page running. If I comment out the animation, CPU usage is back to normal. How can I hardware accelerate this animation to not strain the CPU?

[image: css glow]

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/tokyotech/TutLh/

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulseGlow {
    0% {
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    10% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 1.4em rgba(255,0,0,1),
            0 0 1em rgba(255,0,0,1) inset;
        border-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    }
}

#recordButton {
    display: block;
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
    background: salmon;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-animation: pulseGlow 1s ease-in-out 1s infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the browser decides on when to use hardware acceleration to render something; it's not something you can force on any particular class or style. You can however use certain css properties that are more likely to have a browser use hardware acceleration on it, for example `-webkit-transform: translate3d` (even if you are performing a 2d transform on the page) and `-webkit-transition`.

[See this article for some notes as well as a list of hardware accelerated properties.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/)

As for your particular animation problem, I'm not sure how you'd be able to get a repeating transition to occur without user interaction or using Javascript (alone or in addition to CSS). While you can have `-webkit-transition: box-shadow`, I'm not sure how you would go about repeating your pulse animation since the transition will only run when the property value is changed.

Comment: The animation is repeating because I have `infinite` at the end of the `-webkit-animation` property.

Comment: I realize that, the question was how do you achieve that using `transform` and not `animation` so it will be hardware accelerated.

Comment: I'm afraid it's the webkit-animation cause the cpu grow up, not the box-shadow. 
So please have a try replace the box-shadow with transform or other functions, and check whether the problem still exists.